# Json parser error in MVC

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing xml sting to server side using ajax. Its working fine all data geting saved and its returning desired value from server side. But don't why json showing parser error.

My Code:

```
var XML = "<Review><Question QId='1' QTId='10' /><Question QId='2' QTId='10' /></Review>";
           var pData = { XML: XMLString };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Dashboard/SaveReview',
                type: 'POST',
                data: pData,
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    if (data == "Y") {
                        alert('Success!');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Fail!');
                    }
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    var r = "req:" + req + ", status:" + status + ", error:" + error;
                    alert(r);
                    //alert('Unable to connect server!');
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

MVC :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public JsonResult SaveReview(string XML)
    {
        LibraryModel LM = (LibraryModel)Session["Library"];

        string strResult = dsr.SaveReview(LM.ProjectId, Convert.ToInt32(LM.UserId), 141, null, XML);

        return Json(strResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Image showing its success:-
[image]

But its showing Error:
[image]

Comment: Seems like eventually some error did occur (after the action) and the server returned bunch of HTML. Inspect the "Network" tab in the developer console

Comment: maybe this can help you, references to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816126/simple-jsonresult-returns-parsererror-on-jquery-ajax-method

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.. Thanks guys for your reply. Actually i have missed to set
`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="2.0" /> 
<pages validateRequest="false">` in web config.

Comment: This is really bad solution. You have used `dataType: 'json',` and returning string thats the real problem. use `dataType: 'text'`

Comment: This comment was the solution for my problem when passing parameters to the Crystal report. Thank you so much!